# Where to store token for ReactNative + webview app?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, jwt

We are using session based authentication and trying to migrate to JWT.

Our app has webview (inside native activity or ViewController), and react-native.

If we only had RN, we could store the tokens in `AsyncStorage` and be done with it, but I don't see a webview could read data from `AsyncStorage` .

How can I store tokens so that both webview and RN could use them?

Login process could take place both in webview or RN, but we can make it happen only in one side if it makes things simple.

Comment: Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54885613/authentication-in-a-react-native-webview